# Multiplying a Matrix with a Pure Quaternion

Tags: c++, matrix, matrix-multiplication, quaternions

I have an equation in which I need to multiple a 3 x 3 matrix **M** by a 3 x 1 vector **V** which is stored as a pure quaternion **Q = [0 V]**.

Simple way of doing this is to just get my vector **V** from **Q** and then multiply **M** by **V**. This is the most logical way but at the moment I don't have code written for Matrix-vector multiplication. I do however have code for quaternion-quaternion multiplication.

**The question may seem a little absurd but here it is: Is their a way I can convert this matrix-vector (or Matrix-pure quaternion) multiplication into an equivalent quaternion-quaternion multiplication ?**

Comment: With "stored as pure quaternion" you mean that you have something like an array (or `std::vector`) of 4 doubles the first of  which is 0? Because in that case the matrix vector multiplication code is trivial.

Comment: Your understanding is right. Pure quaternion is  simply a 3d vector i.e [0+xi+yj+zk]

Comment: But you want to perform quaternion-quaternion multiplication. So you need to transform the matrix M into a quaternion. I'm wondering if you already know about this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Quaternion

Comment: You can convert your matrix into quaternion , and multiply it as quaternion by vector

Comment: @Bob__ Actually initially I also converted Matrix M into quaternion and then multiplied it with Q but results obtained are not accurate. For this, it needs to be proved that q(MV) = q(M) q(V) where q is a function which converts its argument (matrix or vector) into a quaternion. Let q(M) = [w+xi+yj+yz] is the correct quaternion representation of M which when multiplied by q(V)=[0 V] = [0+ai+bj+ck] results into q(MV) = [U+li+mj+nk].  a,b,c,l,m,n, U=0 are knowns. w,x,y,z are unknowns. I think there is no solution to the resulting simultaneous linear equations in 4 unknown variables w,x,y,z

Comment: @minorlogic see my last comment in reply to comments made by Bob

Comment: If you are not sure in your conversion function from/to matrix/quaternion? that 
1. Use tested one,  for example "Eigen" library
2. Verify your implementation, convert from matrix and back to matrix and compare matrices. Be sure that quaternion is UNIT

Comment: @minorlogic: I am using Eigen at the moment for converting matrix to quaternion. The point I am raising here is that q(MV) != q(M) q(V). And that is why results are inaccurate.

Comment: You should post the code you use for the transformation. In the link I posted there's an example and some suggestions to make it numerically stable. I'm sorry I don't know nor use Eigen (for now at least)

Comment: [1]: Two Quaternions and their Rotation Matrices: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Quaternion%281%2C-2%2C3%2C2%29%2C+Quaternion%2811%2C-2%2C0%2C-2%29

Comment: [2]: Quaternion-Quaternion Multiplication : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Quaternion%281%2C-2%2C3%2C2%29+multiplied+by+Quaternion%2811%2C-2%2C0%2C-2%29

Comment: [3]: Matrix-Matrix multiplication: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B-4%2F9%2C-8%2F9%2C-1%2F9%7D%2C%7B-4%2F9%2C1%2F9%2C8%2F9%7D%2C%7B-7%2F9%2C4%2F9%2C-4%2F9%7D%7D++%7B%7B121%2F129%2C44%2F129%2C8%2F129%7D%2C%7B-44%2F129%2C113%2F129%2C44%2F129%7D%2C%7B8%2F129%2C-44%2F129%2C121%2F129%7D%7D

Comment: The Matrix representation for [2] is not equal to matrix result of [3]

Comment: The exact result from [3] IS equal to the matrix representation in [2]!

Comment: Quaternion(1,-2,3,2), Quaternion(11,-2,0,-2)

this is NOT unit quaternions. Be sure that your conversion to/from matrix can perform non UNIT quaternions, or normalize it before use

Comment: @Bob__ Oh yes. I see that now.

Comment: @Bob__ would it be then correct to say that q(MV) = q(M) q(V) and q(MN) = q(M) q(N) ?

Comment: I noticed also that in [3] the trace is negative and as pointed out in the wiki link this could make some numerical methods unstable. I don't konw what Eigen uses.

Comment: @nurabha that's a good question for http://math.stackexchange.com/ ;)

Comment: @Bob__ [1] [2] [3] dealt with Matrix - Matrix and so q(MN) = q(M) q(N). Now I present Matrix-vector multiplication where I observe the problem I faced :  [4] https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Quaternion%281%2C-2%2C3%2C2%29%2C+Quaternion%280%2C-2%2C0%2C-2%29, [5] https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Quaternion%281%2C-2%2C3%2C2%29+multiplied+by+Quaternion%280%2C-2%2C0%2C-2%29, [6] http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B-4%2F9%2C-8%2F9%2C-1%2F9%7D%2C%7B-4%2F9%2C1%2F9%2C8%2F9%7D%2C%7B-7%2F9%2C4%2F9%2C-4%2F9%7D%7D++%7B-2%2C0%2C-2%7D.

Comment: @Bob__  Now notice that results of [5] and [6] don't tally. But if I do [7] http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B-4%2F9%2C-8%2F9%2C-1%2F9%7D%2C%7B-4%2F9%2C1%2F9%2C8%2F9%7D%2C%7B-7%2F9%2C4%2F9%2C-4%2F9%7D%7D++%7B%7B0%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C-1%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C0%7D%7D I see [5] and [7] tally.

Comment: @Bob__ So as I see, if F is a function which converts its quaternion argument to a rotation matrix and pure quaternion argument to vector then F(q(M)) F(q(V)) != F(q(MV)). If G is a function which converts its quaternion argument to a rotation matrix then G(q(M)) G(q(V)) == G(q(MV)). In my code I have been using function F but I should be using G

Comment: @minorlogic As I understand your point, the rotation matrix must be normalized before converting it to quaternion and after conversion the resulting quaternion will automatically have norm 1 ? Is vice versa also true i.e. the quaternion must be normalized before converting it into a rotation matrix of norm 1 ?

Comment: @nurabha quaternion msut be unit if conversion procedure can perform only unit quaternions. Rotation matrix can'r be unit or nonunit, it have to be rotataion matrix , orthogonal matrix with determinant 1